# Replace a running executable on mac osx

Tags: macos, executable

I am making an application on Mac and I want to be able to replace a running executable. So while the executable is running I want to be able to replace it with a better version of it. 
As far as I know on Linux you can do that, so the next time the application starts it will start the new executable, but on Windows you can't do that.

So any information about this thing on Mac or any advise how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're implementing an update feature, checkout the [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) framework,
which does exactly what you're looking for, and way more.

In case you only need to replace a running application,
browse the Sparkle project at [GitHub](https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle) to see how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The Foundation framework's `NSFileManager` API has exclusive-use semantics similar to Windows, so you'll struggle to do this with those functions. However, the POSIX filesystem functions you also use on Linux don't have those restrictions, and you can certainly replace running executables.